# Return with a javaFX setOnAction

Tags: java, javafx

Sorry for the vague name but I'm not sure what to call this question, hopefully my explanation helps.

I am writing a program which is kind of a modular text editor using Javafx. There are different components, like specialized text editors or in the future maybe a more visual drag and drop sort of interface.

What I want to do it all users to create a new instance of a component with the menu bar. In my mind the user should launch the program, then be able to navigate to `File>New Component> MySpecializedEditor`, then a new instance of `MySpecializedEditor` will be instantiated and displayed on the stage.

In the past I have done this by creating a class which extends javaFx's `MenuBar` and requiring the `borderPane` in the constructor so I can just directly set the component in the stage from the `MyMenuBar` class.

But this seems like a needlessly coupled way to do it.

Previous Method:

In main javaFx file

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MyMenuBar(borderPane);
```

In MyMenuBar

```
//Create menu path for File>New Component><List of Components>

for(Component c: componentList)
{
    //setOnAction for each element in List of Components that places
    //in the center.
    MenuItem i = new MenuItem(c.getName());
    fileNew.getItems().add(i);//adds component to File>New Component>List of Components
    i.setOnAction(event ->
    {
        borderPane.setCenter((Node) c);//Places clicked component in the center of the screen.
    });
}
```

I was wondering if there was away for me to have a clicked item in `File>New Component><List of Component>` return a reference to the component, so I can display the new component in the main application file? Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is this `borderPane`? Also it's not clear what you're asking - what reference to the component do you want to return? What are you not happy about with your current code?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: @kleopatra FYI, you can type `[mcve]` in a comment and it will expand for you to [mcve].

Comment: @user1803551 didn't know, thanks for the info :)